# The biggest $\gcd(11n+4, 7n+2)$?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

I am having problems solving this problem with greatest common divisors:
What is the greatest common divisor of $11n+4$ and $7n +2$?

I tried Euclidean algorithm, and I tried to deduce the answer and I tried to incorporate

$$\gcd(a,b)\cdot\mathrm{lcm}(a,b)=|ab|$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let use that

$$\gcd(a,b)=\gcd(a,a-b)$$

that is

$$\gcd(11n+4,7n+2)=\gcd(4n+2,7n+2)=\gcd(4n+2,3n)=\gcd(n+2,3n)=\gcd(n+2,2n-2)=\gcd(n+2,n-4)=\gcd(6,n-4)$$

then $\gcd_{MAX}=6$.

Comment: And the maximum is assumed for $n=4$, for example.

Comment: @Servaes Yes indeed we obtain $\gcd(48,30)=6$

Answer (score 0):

If $d\mid 11n+4$ and $d\mid 7n +2$ then $$d\mid 7(11n+4)-11(7n+2)= 6$$

so $d\in \{1,2,3,6\}$. Now, can $d=6$. In this case $6\mid (7n+2)-6n=n+2$ so if $n=6k-2$ then $d=6$ so $\gcd =6$.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{align}
   (11n+4) &= 1(7n+2) + (4n+2) \\
   (7n+2)  &= 2(4n+2) + (-n-2) \\
   (4n+2)  &= -4(-n-2) - 6
\end{align}

This suggests that the biggest gcd must be a divisor of $6$.

Such a value should occur when $n=-2$.

\begin{align}
    11(-2)+4 &= -18 \\
     7(-2)+2 &= -12 \\
   \gcd(-18, -12) &= 6
\end{align}